# Commuting self adjoint operators

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that two commuting, self adjoint operators $A,B$ on a finite dimensional complex inner product space $V$ have identical eigenspaces.
So far I have that the eigenspaces of $A$ are invariant under $B$. Next I tried restricting $B$ to an $A$-eigenspace, but I don't see how to proceed.

Any ideas, hints?

Comment: The need not have identical eigenspaces. Let $B = I$ for example, and $A$ have two distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: This is not true. Consider $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$ and $\pmatrix{2&0\\0&-3}$. What is true is that there exists a common orthonormal basis of diagonalization. To do that, consider the eigenspace decomposition of $A$ and observe that it is stable under $B$ (and $B^*=B$). Then diagonalize the restrictions of $B$ on each eigenspace of $A$.

Comment: However, since you already know that $A$'s eigenspaces are $B$-invariant, an eigenspace of $A$ is an inner product space, and the restriction of $B$ to that is also self-adjoint.

Comment: True. then let's formulate it as "There are $V_k < V$, such that $V_k$ is a simultaneous eigenspace of $A,B$. Now better?

Comment: Yes, Daniel, I figured that out too. But how do I go on from here?

Comment: Let $E$ be the eigenspace of $A$ under consideration. $B\lvert_E \colon E \to E$ is diagonalizable, with orthogonal eigenspaces.